# R: Make all row values NA if one value is NA

Tags: r

I want to do the following. If one value in the row is `NA`, then replace all the values of a row in a `data frame` by `NA`. Example:

```
 df <- data.frame( id=c(NA,20,30,40,NA,60), value=c(15,NA,35,45,55,65))
```

The output would be

```
  id value
1 NA    NA
2 NA    NA
3 30    35
4 40    45
5 NA    NA
6 60    65
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
df[!!rowSums(is.na(df)),] <- NA
df
#  id value
#1 NA    NA
#2 NA    NA
#3 30    35
#4 40    45
#5 NA    NA
#6 60    65
```

Or

```
df[with(df, is.na(id)|is.na(value)),] <- NA
```

Comment: I know I'm necro'ing an old post of yours, but what does the `!!` before `rowSums()` do here?

Comment: @Dunois `rowSums` returns the sum of the logical matrix.  By negating first `!`, it changes all the 0 sum rows to TRUE and other values to FALSE,  WIth the second `!`, it flips TRUE -> FALSE and viceversa

Comment: gotcha. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what others have posted, you can use the `complete.cases` function:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(NA, 20, 30, 40, NA, 60),
                 value = c(15, NA, 35, 45, 55, 65))
complete.cases(df)
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
df[complete.cases(df), ]
##   id value
## 3 30    35
## 4 40    45
## 6 60    65
```

and you can set the incomplete rows to `NA`:

```
df[!complete.cases(df), ] <- NA
df
##   id value
## 1 NA    NA
## 2 NA    NA
## 3 30    35
## 4 40    45
## 5 NA    NA
## 6 60    65
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with the `apply` function:

```
R>df[ apply(is.na(df), 1, any), ] <- NA
R>df
  id value
1 NA    NA
2 NA    NA
3 30    35
4 40    45
5 NA    NA
6 60    65
```